# Tournaments, Players and Match Relations

Tags: sql, database-design

I have multiple players in multiple tournaments in multiple seasons (tables: player, tournament, season). So a match between two players has to reference a specific tournament and a specific season.

```
table match
    id
    season_id
    tournament_id
    player_home
    player_away
```

Let's say it would probably be natural to assign players to tournaments for obvious benefits. Could I do a one-to-many table between seasons and tournaments (call the table competition) and then do a many-to-many table for competitions and players?

```
table competition
    id
    season_id
    tournament_id

table competition_player
    id
    competition_id
    player_id

table match
    id
    competition_id
    player_home
    player_away
```

Or is there a more simple/better way to achieve this?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Joins are the whole point of relational databases.

Comment: What is it you want to do with the system?  Are you building an OLAP system (eg:  analyzing player performance), or an OLTP system (eg:  an online match-building and scoring service)?

Comment: OLTP. Results of matches are put into ranking tables for each tournament.

Comment: @freddieoff I updated my answer with a fiddle. Just to show the relations. I didn't really care if I displayed the name or the Id of the linked tables. I just wanted to test my query. Hope you enjoy :)

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk thanks for taking the time. Maybe a normalization issue with the same tournament names being repeated over multiple seasons. And without the many-to-many between tournament and player, it's probably a bit difficult to see who belongs where.

Answer (score 0):

### SqlFiddle

Very basic but still you can see the relationship. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8652/7/0).

### Structure

**Tables**

- **Players**

  ```
  --------------------------
  |Id | Name | OtherInfo   |
  --------------------------
  | 1 | John | Player Info |
  --------------------------
  | 2 |  Tom | Player Info |
  --------------------------
  ```
- **Seasons**

  ```
  -----------------------------------
  |Id | SeasonName    | SeasonInfo  |
  -----------------------------------
  |01 | MyFirstSeason | Season Info |
  -----------------------------------
  ```
- **Tournements**

  ```
  ------------------------------------
  | Id | SeasonId | TournamentName   |
  ------------------------------------
  |001 |    01    | MyFirstTournament|
  ------------------------------------
  ```
- **Encounters**

  ```
  ---------------------------------------
  | Id | FirstPlayerId | SecondPlayerId |
  ---------------------------------------
  | A  |       1       |       2        |  
  ---------------------------------------
  ```
- **Matchs**

  ```
  -----------------------------------------------
  | Id | TournamentId | EncounterId | MatchInfo |
  -----------------------------------------------
  |0001|     001      |      A      | Some Info |
  -----------------------------------------------
  ```

Thing is you're using to many keys for nothing. You just need to take a step back a think about the design. I know I took out some columns but it's just for the example's sake. I'm sure you understand where to put them back. I just wanted to show the relationships between those tables.

### Query

Let's imply you just want basic information (once again just for the example)

```
Select m.Id, 
t.TournamentName,
s.SeasonName, 
(SELECT pl.Name FROM Players pl 
 JOIN Encounters en ON pl.Id = en.FirstPlayerId 
 WHERE pl.Id = en.FirstPlayerId) AS [FirstPlayerName],
(SELECT pl.Name FROM Players pl 
 JOIN Encounters en ON pl.Id = en.SecondPlayerId
 WHERE pl.Id = en.SecondPlayerId) As [SecondPlayerName],
m.MatchInfo 
FROM Matchs m 
JOIN Tournaments t ON m.TournamentId = t.Id
JOIN Encounters e ON m.EncounterId = e.Id
JOIN Seasons s ON  t.SeasonId = s.Id
```